# my php adds a blank entry before i even press submit, any ideas?

Tags: php, database

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>
    <body>            
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            title: <input type="text" name="title" /><br><br>
            name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br><br>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); 
            if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("msg360db1", $con);

            $sql="INSERT INTO members (title, name)
                VALUES
                ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[name]')";

            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "1 record added";
            echo mysql_error();
            mysql_close($con)
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my form that i will enter the information onto then when add is clicked it should add it to my database but instead it adds when the page loads

Comment: Its `<!DOCTYPE` , not `<DOCTYPE!`

Comment: You need to sanitize your code. It is very vulnerable to sql INJECTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for submit click on page load

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $con = mysql_connect("213.171.200.70","bjenkins","password"); 
  if (!$con)
  {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
        mysql_select_db("msg360db1", $con);
  $sql="INSERT INTO members (title, name)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[name]')";

   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo "1 record added";
   echo mysql_error();
   mysql_close($con)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You must check like:

```
if(isset($_POST['title']){

 $sql="INSERT INTO members (title, name)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[name]')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        echo "1 record added";
        echo mysql_error();
        mysql_close($con)

}
```

Then it will save record only if there is some data in post.

Comment: And there is a high possibility of SQL injection in this SQL statment

Comment: @Rossco this question is about solving user's problem.. not about `prevention from sql injections`..

Comment: I have only given him solution of his problem SQL injection should be cotrolled by him :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code is run on any page on every load time.  As such, when you first load the page to type in your data, you are in effect adding the blank entry. Then when you submit the page, a second entry with data is added.

As such you need to check if the page has been submitted or not.  Wrap your php code with a check for `$_POST`.

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
        $con = mysql_connect("213.171.200.70","bjenkins","K3rrydixon"); 
        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("msg360db1", $con);

        $sql="INSERT INTO members (title, name)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[name]')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "1 record added";
        echo mysql_error();
        mysql_close($con)
}
```

Also, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated - use some newer constructs like PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check, if the submit button was pressed or if it's a normal page view:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
// Do your SQL-Stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see the beginning of your code. You might be skip checking if $_POST is set and write into database in case it is.

EDIT: Interesting, now I see the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  **But this code is not sanitized and  is vulnerable for sql 
injection. please sanitize your code.**
```

//check if both values are set.

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['name'])){


    $sql="INSERT INTO members (title, name)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[name]')";

            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
              {
              die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
              }
            echo "1 record added";
            echo mysql_error();
            mysql_close($con)
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed on the server before the html is rendered by the browser or even generated. In your case, by the time the form gets displayed (or submitted) the php code is already executed.

And since the variables $_POST[title] and $_POST[name] are blank when the php code is executed, a database row with no (blank) values is inserted.

What you need to do is to check whether the form is submitted and execute the insert queries only if the form is submitted. For this you can add conditions as mentioned in other answers